# Resutl showing book is not defined in console

Tags: reactjs

I used to show my New arrival page from Home page when i select books. I Planned to show only a book that is selected in Home page book list. But its now showing in New arrival page right now. Please help me to get rid off.

```
 import React from "react";
    
    const BookDetails = (props) => {
      console.log(props.book);
    
      if (props.book === null) return <div></div>;
      return (
        <div>
          <h3>{props.book.bookName}</h3>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default BookDetails;
```

(This is another code i used my onclick fucntion)

```
 import React from "react";
import Book from "../Representational/Book";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";


const ComponentList = (props) => {
  return props.books.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <Book
        bookName={item.bookName}
        writer={item.writer}
        publish={item.publish}
        key={item.id}
        selectedBookHandler={()=>props.selectedBookHandler(Book)}
      />
    );
  });
};

export default withRouter(ComponentList);
```

(Below are codes as main component)

```
import { Component } from "react";
import ComponentList from "./Lists/ComponentList";
import BookList from "../Assets/BookList";
import NewBook from "./Representational/NewBook";
import About from './Representational/About';
import {Route, NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';
import BookDetails from "./Representational/BookDetails";

class MainComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      books: BookList,
      selectedBook: null
    }
  }
  
  selectedBookHandler = books=>{
    this.setState({
      selectedBook: books
    })

  }
  
  render() {
     const newCopy = (
        <ComponentList
          books={this.state.books}
          selectedBookHandler={this.selectedBookHandler}
        />
      );

    return (
      <div className="book-project">
        <nav className="nav-bar">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <NavLink to="/" exact>Home</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to="/new">New Arrival</NavLink></li>
            <li><NavLink to="/about-us">About Us</NavLink></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div>
          <Route path="/" exact render={()=> newCopy} />
          <Route path="/new" exact component={NewBook}/>
          <Route path="/about-us" exact component= {About}/>
          <BookDetails book={this.state.selectedBook}/>
        </div>

        <div className="head">
          <h1 className="appHeading head">New Book List</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="btn">

          <button onClick={this.toggleBook}>Toggle</button>
          <input type="text" onChange={this.changeInputState} />
        </div>

       
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MainComponent;
```

Please Help me.

Comment: when you call `selectedBookHandler`?

Comment: to show single book properties only out of five in New Arrival Page.

Comment: show this code..

Comment: shouldn't you be passing the actual book `item` rather than a `Book` an object type?

Comment: I solve the problems! Thanks for helping me.